# How to override ssl (https) settings on Symfony

Tags: symfony

In my app, I have set up the routes and security to use secure connection for certain routes:

```
<route id="store_checkout" pattern="/checkout" scheme="https">
    <default key="_controller">Store:Store:checkout</default>
</route>


access_control:
    - { path: ^/checkout, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
```

However, since this app is open-source and can run on any server (which may not have SSL), I want to allow users to disable/ignore SSL requirement (at their own risks) if they choose to do so.

Currently I can think of several ways:

1. I can have 2 routing files (1 with ssl, 1 without) and also 2 security files. Then based on user's selection on installation the app can decide which file to use
2. Or perhaps I can also customize router's generate function to generate http or https links based on the _scheme settings AND the SSL status (which user can enable/disable if they have/dont have SSL cert)

Is there any better way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I know the answer is late, but if you stumble upon this when googling:

Just add a to parameters.yml:

```
url_scheme: https
```

And in your security.yml:

```
- { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: %url_scheme% }
```